# send post params with a link_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to call an api endpoint on my rails app.
I cannot find the way to pass post params from `link_to` nor from `form_tag`

`link_to '/v1/my_endpoint/approve', data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" },  remote: true, method: :post, id: 'approve-id' do 'link_name' end`

I want together with the above link to pass some post params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link_to` isn't going to do what you need. You could pass query params that way, but not form params.

You need to use a form, or write some javascript to submit the request for you.

Rails has a handy `button_to` helper which will create a small form, presented in your UI as a single button. You can add params to that quite easily:

```
<%= button_to "button label", "/v1/my_endpoint/approve", remote: true, params: { id: "approve-id", something: "else" } %>
```

If you wanted, you could use CSS to style that button as a link.

You can read about the `button_to` method in the docs here:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to